# When debugging a .NET Core process on linux via LLDB SOS, how to break on First Chance Exception?

Tags: debugging, .net-core, lldb, sos

I am attaching an lldb debugger to a .net core process along with sos plugin installed. I am observing it only breaks for the unhandled exception. I would like to break on the inner exception when it exactly happens. How do this with LLDB and sos?

Comment: Running break set -E c++ helps. I guess this is my best bet.

Comment: Generally, the debugger has to know how each language implements exception throwing to be able to break on exception throw.  lldb doesn't have any built-in support for .NET...  However, the Itanium project introduced a general unwind mechanism which outlived Itanium and was adopted on macOS both for the C++ exception throwing and ObjC exception throwing.  The C++ exception throw catching in lldb stops at its low-level throw point.  It would make sense for the .NET folks to use the same mechanism, which is probably why setting the C++ exception throw breakpoint catches the .NET ones as well.

Comment: This question is about [SOS plugin](https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/blob/d2be8fc97495a8b06fa5e800c32af09ff7893238/documentation/installing-sos-instructions.md#installing-sos-on-linux-and-macos), which is what dotnet team has implemented for lldb and does what Jim is suggesting. However, I do not know how to catch all the managed unhandled exceptions with sos. I suspect `bpmd` command does that; see documentation in lldb REPL by running `soshelp bpmd`.